# How to use jotform API to display forms

Tags: php, html, api, jotform

I am looking to find a way to display forms that are created in `JotForm` using the APIs. Basically, I'd like to make a call with the API and pass an ID to the API and then have it pull the necessary information back from JotForms in order to render the form that as been created in JotForm itself.

I've done a little research and I haven't found anything that suits my needs just yet. Was wondering if anyone knew of a set of scripts (possibly php) that would allow me to complete such a task?

Answer (score -1):

Please visit this website for your required language code:

http://api.jotform.com/docs/

Comment: That doesn't tell me how to actually render the forms tho. Unless I have missed something.

Comment: For PHP code please dowbload it from gtihub: https://github.com/jotform/jotform-api-php

Comment: Thanks! That seems to get me on my way some. I'd love to find a script that I could pass a JotForm ID to and it would render that form for me

Comment: Downvoted for it being such a lazy answer. Most of us already know about the docs.